# How to find different fragments of a file in HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Is there a way to find out where have the fragments of the file I have put in Hdfs gone? I mean the information as to where the file fragments stored in hdfs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the fsck command:

```
#> hadoop fsck /path/to/file -files -blocks -locations -racks
```

This lists for the file, the blocks and their associated metadata:

- block name/ID
- block length
- block replication
- locations (datanodeIp:port)
- rack (prefix datanode ip's with the associated rack id)

For example:

```
/user/chris/file1.txt 123 bytes, 1 block(s): OK
0. blk_432678432632_3426532 len=123 repl=2 [/rack1/1.2.3.4:50010, /rack2/4.5.6.7:50010]
```

Comment: np, can you accept if you don't need any further information?

Comment: Can it tell me in what IP Addresses the blocks are stored? It does tell me how many into the file is divided. However can it also list the IP Addresses of the nodes where the blocks are stored? Or is there any other mechianism through which we get to know that?

Comment: the `-locations` should list the datanode IDs - are you seeing machine names rather than IPs in the output?

Comment: No, I am able to see the IP Addresses. Thanks Chris.

Comment: So what does yours list? I'm guessing the machine names of the data nodes